# Wire adapter: assign value to data array / Error: Cannot assign to read only property (despite shallow copy)

Tags: javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

I try to assign a new value (string + var) to a array field. I did a shallow copy, but still receive the mentioned error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thx !!

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import initMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MCWrapperController.initMethod";

export default class Carousel extends LightningElement {
  results;
  
  @wire(initMethod, { cmsContentType: 'cms_image', cmsTopic: 'Home' }) 
  
  getResults(response) {
    const {data, error} = response;

    if (data) {
      arrCopy = [...data];
      arrCopy.forEach(imgUrl => {
        // I try to assign a string and a var, eg ... = "https://..." + {url}
        imgUrl.contentNodes.source.url = "string" // for testing only string
      });
      this.results = arrCopy;
      
      console.log ('cms', this.results);
     } else if (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, that shallow copy only changes first level, but deeper levels are still wrapped into readonly proxy, so I recommend doing like this

```
 getResults(response) {
    const {data, error} = response;

    if (data) {
      this.results = data.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {
        contentNodes: {
          source: {
            url: 'string'
          }
        }
      }));

      console.log ('cms', this.results);
    } else if (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
```

so you create a separate object and do not modify returned from the Apex.

Not sure about this deep assignment, you might want to do it via separate variable, but Object.assign will do it's job `const tmp= Object.assign({}, item)`

**UPDATE**

This deep assignment doesn't work, one minute, I'll update to the option with additional variable

**UPDATE2**
this deep properties are sad( Either just JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)) or set it somewhere else

Comment: you put me in the right direction. I went for `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify))` and used than a `forEach` to modify the fields. Works perfect now and reminded me to learn more about the security concept.